# Changing to background/text color of a ComboBox depending on the value chosen

Tags: c#, python, wpf

I would like to be able to change the background color of a combo box depending on the value chosen in a wpf.

I have tried using python to do this  but I am new to programming (and IT in general)

Could you point me in the right direction, please?

Current code:

```
from System import Decimal

from System.Windows import MessageBox

from System.Windows import LogicalTreeHelper

from System.Windows.Input import KeyEventHandler

from System.Windows.Media import Brush, Brushes, ColorConverter

import sys

from time import sleep

class PythonDemo(object):  

    def Init(self,_tikitDbAccess,_tikitSender):

        self._tikitDbAccess=_tikitDbAccess
        self._tikitSender=_tikitSender

        self.combobox=LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(self._tikitSender, 'ComboBox1')

        self.combobox.LostFocus += self.ColorChange


        def ColorChange(self,sender,e):
            #List of things i have tried
            self.combobox.Background.Color="Red"# also tried "#FF00FF00"

            self.combobox.Background="Red"

            self.combobox.SelectedItem.Background="Red"

oPythonDemo=PythonDemo
```

Comment: You should add code of whatever you have tried and the exact problem you faced when trying it!

Comment: I see you have a c# tag, is a c# solution fine?

Answer (score 0):

I see you have included a `C#` tag, so I will give you a solution in C#. If you need a solution in Python I can't help you, but you made it sound as if you didn't care, so here is my best effort.

I don't know what your XAML looks like, so I can only give you a rough implementation, but you should be able to implement this easily.

Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" SelectionChanged="ComboBox1_SelectionChanged" Height="50" Width="Auto">
        <ComboBoxItem Name="GreenOption" Content="Green"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="BlueOption" Content="Blue"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="PinkOption" Content="Pink"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="RedOption" Content="Red"/>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Again, that should be replaced with whatever you happen to have, this is just an example. Here is the C#:

```
using System.Windows.Media;


/*The rest of your code goes here*/


private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var foo = sender as ComboBox;
        var bar = foo.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;

        switch (bar.Name)
        {
            case "GreenOption":
                foo.Background = Brushes.Green;
                break;
            case "PinkOption":
                foo.Background = Brushes.Pink;
                break;
            case "RedOption":
                foo.Background = Brushes.Red;
                break;
            case "BlueOption":
                foo.Background = Brushes.Blue;
                break;
        }
    }
/* Or Here */
```

It's very possible that there are more elegant solutions, and I don't know how it would be done in Python, but the basic principle should be the same. Make sure you remember the `using System.Windows.Media;` directive, and this should work like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for you help @Cubemaster. I have tried to implement this and I get the following error:  Failed to create a 'SelectionChanged' from the text 'ComboBox1_SelectionChanged'

Comment: Try going into the XAML and deleting and retyping the `SelectionChanged` portion of the tag. The autocomplete should say something like "Complete Method" or "Add New Event Handler". Click that if it comes up, and put the code into that handler. 

If that doesn't work, let me know